# Uppercase T works in Jupyter Notebook but throws PyCharm error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

A notebook I pulled from a GitHub project sets a variable thusly: `wgts['0.encoder.weight'] = T(new_w)`

This works fine in the notebook, but when I try to use the same code in a script (using PyCharm) it flags an error: `Unresolved reference 'T'`

Both the notebook and the script import the same packages.

I read elsewhere that the uppercase `T` represents a transpose but the syntax is `something.T`

Is there another approach that will do exactly the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: Runs just fine on a linux server. Must be that PyCharm just doesn't like it. Still curious what the "T" in ```T(foo)``` means.

Comment: I believe the answer's in [this FastAI Forum thread](https://forums.fast.ai/t/nameerror-name-t-is-not-defined-deep-learning-part-2-dl2-lesson-10-imdb/29699). You should be more clear about where you got the code from when you ask a question so we don't have to go and Google it for you.

Comment: Thank you Mihai for the link. My objective was to determine if this was standard Python syntax that I was unaware of. And also curious why something that worked in Jupyter would not work in PyCharm even with the same imports. _That_ question remains unanswered but falls into the category of "interesting but not a blocker."

Comment: I'm not sure what the reason might be. Are you sure your PyCharm and Jupyter are set up the same way? It could be they use different Python environments or interpreters. Does the `import torch.tensor as T` line work, or do you get an ImportError?

Comment: The import worked fine, thanks. I have a Python virtual environment set up for fastai and that's the env my Python project is pointing to. Not sure but I suspect the issue is the FastAI version. Tip off is with this (got this from the fastai forum thread you pointed me to). In both the notebook and PyCharm project the code calls 'LanguageModelData'. PyCharm flags it as an unresolved reference. But if I replace it with `TextLMDataBunch` PyCharm is happy. More below; running out of characters.

Comment: If you're interested, what I'm doing is creating a script that can be deployed to the GPU to train the final version of the backbone NLP model. In many cases this function runs longer than you care to rely on keeping a notebook open. If you fire it up with nohup on the GPU it will run to completion even after you shut down the notebook. I'm testing it right now and if it works as expected I'll put it on GitHub.

Comment: If you found the answer to your question you can write an answer and accept it after a certain amount of time has passed. Then others will know there's a solution to the problem. It might be good to also clarify in your question where the code came from (fastai) so that others with the same problem can find it more easily.